# Viewing Sharepoint files on my desktop - not on Sharepoint site

Tags: view

When i send a link to a file that is stored in sharepoint it goes to the sharepoint site how do I just have the file open without going to sharepoint site

Comment: This is a really bad idea.  Allowing people to access content stored in SharePoint without going to the SharePoint site (i.e. using WebDAV) circumvents the tools in SharePoint that are put in place for a reason (e.g. metadata, versioning, check in/check out).

Answer (score 1):

The most SharePoint files are stored in the DB. You can access it through Windows Explorer typing `\\yourSharepointUrl\DavWWWRoot` (if you have persmissions)

Comment: And when using SSL the path should be in the form of "\\SharePointURL@SSL@port\DavWWWRoot\path\".

Answer (score 0):

Unless you store the file on your desktop, otherwise you have to SharePoint either view or download it.

Another Option is,to use the Onedrive for business and sync the document to you desktop for offline use. [check this one](http://www.learningsharepoint.com/2012/12/12/how-to-work-with-documents-offline-in-sharepoint-2013/)

Or you can open the document with explorer and download all files then use